# Excel - unable to open spreadsheet for writing

Tags: ms-office, high-sierra

I have a new iMac which I am setting up. I used Migration Assistant to transfer my files from my old MacBook. Both Macs are running High Sierra.

I was attempting to open Excel2008 to edit a couple of spreadheets, and got a bizarre error message 
    `Mercer.xlsx` is being modified by (my name).
    Open as Read-Only, or chose Notify to be alerted when it is available.

I have tried a number of things.
I went to my MacBook, made sure the files and Excel were closed, copied to a portable HDD.
I tried replacing the files, same result.

I opened one of the files from the HDD, and saved it to the Documents directory, and actually modified the file by adding a new line.
When I tried to re-open I got the same error.

I cleared all extended attributes, but this did not seem to help.
    com.apple.FinderInfo       32 
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS      16 
    com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags    42

Does anyone have any ideas. These spreadsheets contain more than 10 years worth of data.

Comment: You might have a hidden temporary file causing this error. Open Terminal and change directory to the folder in which your problem file is located. Type `ls -al`. Do you see a version of Mercer.xlsx preceded by a tilde and dollar sign?

Comment: @PaulBrady Thanks - there were 3 hidden files. When I last did the TimeMachine backup the spreadsheets were open, which presumably caused the problem.

Comment: Did you delete those files via the terminal, or did you resolve your issue some other way?

Comment: @PaulBrady actually I deleted them with my own FileManager QuollEyeTree. I had to enable Hidden files to see them.